# Fan noise at startup on Lenovo Thinkpad E14 laptop after BIOS update

Tags: bios, updates, fan, thinkpad, noise

I just updated my BIOS on brand new Lenovo Thinkpad E14 laptop and then I start hearing loud fan noise at startup? What is the issue? I have never even heard fan kick in on this laptop till today until the update. The name of the BIOS update is Thinkpad Bios Update 10.

Comment: How long do the fans keep on working?

Comment: Where did you get the BIOS update from? Should be r16uj11w.exe